# Supress unused labels in dotplot panel

Tags: r, lattice

I have the following data frame

```
   ds <- data.frame(iso2c=as.factor(c(rep("AR",3),rep("BR",3),rep("DE",3),rep("US",3))),

             region= as.factor(c(rep("LATAM",6),rep("DEVELOPED",6))),

             year= rep(c(1979,1989,1999),4),

             value= c( 47.0 , 28.6,  20.8, 100.0,  64.2,  35.4,  16.0 ,  9.0,   5.5,  15.6,  11.6,   8.6))                 )
```

and would like to plot the data in a dotplot, as follows,

```
  library(lattice)
  dotplot(iso2c~value | region, data=ds, groups=year,pch=19,col="dark blue",cex=1.3,ylab="country",,layout=c(1,2))
```

Problem is, region being a partition of iso2c, i have two empty rows in each panel (AR and BR are empty in DEVELOPED, US and DE in LATAM).

Changing the panel function to drop the levels unused in that panel (see following code) does not work.

```
dotplot(iso2c~value | region, data=ds, groups=year,pch=19,col="dark blue",cex=1.3,ylab="country",layout=c(1,2),
     panel=function(x,y,...) {
       panel.dotplot(x,droplevels(y),...)    
    },

)
```

Is there a way to supress unused levels in a panel?

Comment: In such situations it's probably better to flatten the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `scales` argument in the `dotplot` function to indicate that you'd like the y-axis to scale freely. This will then include only those levels that are present in each panel:

```
dotplot(iso2c~value | region, data=ds, groups=year,pch=19,
    col="dark blue",cex=1.3,ylab="country",layout=c(1,2),
    scales = list(y = list(relation = "free")))
```

[image]